# Create array of regex matches javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I want to create an array of matches for my regex expression in javascript.

It should look like: `['<:S_egirl:1023714296590499882>', '<a:eee:1023672889490284606>']`
However, my code currently only makes an array with 1 item which includes all the matches.

The expression is: `/<:.+:(\d+)>/gm`

And my code is `const parsed_emotes = [].concat(emotes.match(/<:.+:(\d+)>/gm)); console.log(parsed_emotes);`

I've been stuck on this for hours, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your `.+` non-greedy with `?`. Compare the output of these two matches:

```js
'<:hello:1234> <:hello:1234>'.match(/<:.+:(\d+)>/gm)
// Produces ['<:hello:1234> <:hello:1234>']
```

Vs a non-greedy match:

```js
'<:hello:1234> <:hello:1234>'.match(/<:.+?:(\d+)>/gm)
// Produces ['<:hello:1234>', '<:hello:1234>']
```